# Active Storage not saving to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rails-activestorage

I have been setting my active storage really boilerplate.
I do not know why its overriding my **:amazon** setting with **:local**

`rails -V #rake, version 13.0.1`

`ruby -v #ruby 2.6.6p146`

```
#config/storage.yml
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>
  region: <%= ENV['S3_REGION'] %>
  bucket: <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] %>
# all ENV variables are set and they return the property values
```

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
# I checked this in the console and I 
# Rails.application.config.active_storage.service
# => :amazon
```

```
#app/models/special.rb
class Special < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :main_image
  ...
end
```

in my view

```
#app/views/specials/index.html.haml
...
= image_tag special.main_image,   width: '50px' if special.main_image.present?
...
<img width="50px" src="https://nws-prod.herokuapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBZVU9IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--79f30620b94d04457f50b7fa0eb11c529ae77629/gown%20fda%203.jpg">
```

So the problem that after I upload something it saving the file as if it was local

I am not sure where to look

Thanks for all the help

Comment: If you are running the application in development environment configure it in development.rb file.

Comment: sad to say that is in production. I had also changed my #config/environments/development.rb file in the same way and I cant seem to upload to AWS

Comment: Few questions, have u restarted the application after saving the file and if so, are sure the files are being uploaded to local storage path.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted the applications many times. When I inspect the file it is pointing to my local file, also as its in production server when the server restart the images are gone

Comment: Can you add more specifics to your question. I.e model code of the attachment and URL it is generating when accessing.

Comment: I just updated my model code, as well as my view with its HTML output

Comment: The blob url is common for all storage files. It can be s3 url. One way to make sure is use special.main_image.service_url. If this returns s3 url then there is no problem, if it returns local url then there must be a problem with the storage

Comment: sad to say that 'Rails.application.config.active_storage.service' does return `amazon` but my images keep getting deleted on restart :(

Comment: If you have access then check if the files exists in s3 bucket. If the files exists then the problem is with the url expiry

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the below in `config/environments/development.rb`

```rb
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

You can also try the following and check the URL, if it loads a S3 URL everything is working.

```rb
special.main_image..service_url
```